# picking balls from $3$ jugs

Tags: probability

In jug a there are $3$ black balls and $2$ red balls,In jug b there are $2$ black balls and $3$ red balls, In jug c there are $3$ black balls and $3$ red balls: 
$$\text{Jug a: }\underline{\bigcirc\times3\color{red}\bigcirc\times2}\\
\text{Jug b: }\underline{\bigcirc\times2\color{red}\bigcirc\times3}\\
\text{Jug c: }\underline{\bigcirc\times3\color{red}\bigcirc\times3}$$

Picking one ball from jug a, one ball from jug b and two balls from jug c (with no replacement)

> Find the probability that we picked at least one black ball and at least one red ball

---

**My attempt:**

*step one:*

For jug a: Let $R$ be the event that we picked a red ball $P(R)=2/5$

For jug b: $P(R)=3/5$

For jug c: $P(R)=3/6\times 2/5 $

So the probability that all the four balls are red is $\frac 2 5\times \frac 3 5\times \frac{3}{6 }\times\frac{2}{5}=\frac{6}{125}=0.048$

*step two:*

For jug a: Let $B$ be the event that we picked a black ball $P(B)=3/5$

For jug b: $P(B)=2/5$

For jug c: $P(B)=3/6\times 2/5 $

So the probability that all the four balls are black is $\frac 3 5\times \frac 2 5\times \frac{3}{6 }\times\frac{2}{5}=\frac{6}{125}=0.048$

*step three:*

So the probability that we will pick at least one black ball and at least one red ball is $1-(0.048+0.048)=\frac{113}{125}=\bbox[yellow]{0.904}$

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: The procedure is right. I have not checked the arithmetic. For $4$ black you could have used the symmetry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Nice use of complementary counting.